# How to set Backbone model to an objcet's child array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, backbone.js

I've got an backbone app which gets data from json array and appends to the html, but when i try to change json data array to an object i coundn't manage to set related array to my model.

Note: i've took an example of the backbone structure from this website: http://bardevblog.wordpress.com/2012/01/16/understanding-backbone-js-simple-example/

Here is working code:

**JSON**

```
[
        {
            "id": 0,
            "title": "ABC",
            "list": [
                {
                    "type": 2,
                    "date": "21.9.2012"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "CBA",
            "list": [
                {
                    "type": 2,
                    "date": "16.8.2013"
                },
                {
                    "type": 3,
                    "date": "30.9.2014"
                }
            ]
        },
]
```

**Backbone:**

```
var App = {
    Models: {},
    Collections: {},
    Views: {},
    Templates:{}
}

App.Templates.items = _.template($('#tmplt-projects').html());
App.Templates.item = _.template($('#tmplt-project').html());

App.Models.Items = Backbone.Model.extend({});
```

Collection & Views:

```
App.Collections.Items = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: App.Models.Items,
    url: 'json/app.json'
});
App.Views.Items = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#projects'),
    template: App.Templates.items,

    initialize: function () {
        this.collection.on('sync', this.render, this);
    },

    render: function(){
        $(this.el).html(this.template());
        this.addAll();
    },

    addAll: function () {
        this.collection.each(this.addOne);
    },

    addOne: function (model) {
        view = new App.Views.Items({ model: model });
        $('#projects ol', this.el).append(view.render());
    }
});
App.Views.Item = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    className: 'row',
    template: App.Templates.item,

    render: function () {
        return $(this.el).append(this.template(this.model.toJSON())) ;
    }
});
```

Code doesn't work when i change array's structure to object and can not found a solution to work this thing.

```
{
    "attr1" : "3",
    "attr2" : "5",
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "title": "ABC",
            "list": [
                {
                    "type": 2,
                    "date": "21.9.2012"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "CBA",
            "list": [
                {
                    "type": 2,
                    "date": "16.8.2013"
                },
                {
                    "type": 3,
                    "date": "30.9.2014"
                }
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

But i can not work this code when i try to convert json data like this, i want to set backbone model to items object and ignore other 2 objects.
How can i set `items` array to model ?

```
addAll: function () {

        console.log(this.collection.models[0].attributes.items);
        // this returns me the array of items
        // but i can not set this to model
        this.collection.each(this.addOne);
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add a [parse function](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse) to your collection, so when the json returns from the server you return the `items` array (which is the array of model attributes to be added to the collection):

```
App.Collections.Items = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: App.Models.Items,
    url: 'json/app.json',
    parse: function(response) {
        return response.items;
    }
});
```

This way your collection should be initialized as with the previous json response, and attr1, attr2 should be ignored.

Comment: Daniel is it possible to get `attr1` object's value from this view ? Thanks agains, appreciated.

Comment: You could keep its value in your parse function as in `this.attr1 = response.attr1`. So in your items view, you could access it with  `this.collection.attr1`